# Deactivate Info Log popup - Python: Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, interface, error

Some scripting errors generate this error popup.
Clicking the red X doesn't close the error message, but opens up Blender's Info Log.
It fades aways after a few seconds, but during that I can't click on any workspace tabs, because they are hidden behind the popup.

Is there a way to get rid of the red popup entirely? Why doesn't it just print the error message  to the console in the usual way here?
[image: Blender Info Log popup]

Comment: Those error messages usually appear in the middle of the bottom status bar, not the top menu bar. Have you changed Blender's UI layout at all?

Comment: My Status bar is closed. (doesn't hold relevant information for me anymore, since scene statistics moved to the viewport.)

Comment: I guess that's why the error messages are appearing in the menu bar in that case but since there are no developers here to ask...

Comment: Should be gone by deactivating `Preferences > Keymap > Window > Update Reports Display`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the entry in:
Preferences > Keymap > Window > Update Reports Display

(as @relaxed pointed out in the comments)